# How to create a cross reference check?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**TLDR:** I am trying to display a reference from **User A** to **User B** and I want **User B** to be able to recognize there is a reference from **User A**.

In my application, I have a section where I connect **Users** to each other in order to see their relationships (ex. Brother, Sister and etc.) This section is called Case Cross Reference.

I connect Users with their **Case GUID**.

*Example*:

If I want to connect **User A** to **User B**, it simply puts the User that I'm connecting from as **From_Case** and another User as **To_Case**.

[image: Cross Reference table]

***Current situation***:

I'm currently able to display the connection from **User A** to **User B** and vice versa but when I go to **User B**, it doesn't show the right **Case Number** or **Relationship**.

```
ToCases = await db.CaseCrossReference
                    .Include(x => x.Relationship)
                    .Include(x => x.Type)
                    .Include(x => x.Case2.CaseNumber)
                    .Where(x => (x.From_Case == cid || x.To_Case == cid)
                                && x.Deleted == false)
                    .Select(o => new CaseCrossReferenceToRelationshipViewModel()
                    {
                        CaseIdFrom = o.From_Case,
                        CaseIdTo = o.To_Case,
                        CaseCrossReferenceId = o.CaseCrossReferenceId,
                        CaseNumber = o.Case2.CaseNumber == null ? null : o.Case2.CaseNumber.CaseNumberPrefix + "-" + o.Case2.CaseNumber.Number,
                        LivingTogether = o.LivingTogether,
                        Split = o.Split,
                        SplitDate = o.SplitDate,
                        SplitReason = o.SplitReason,
                        Type = o.Type.Definition,
                        RelationshipDefinition = o.Relationship.Definition
                    }).ToListAsync()


foreach (var cases in model.ToCases)
            {
                    // Check for any reverse relationships
                    var reference = await db.CaseCrossReference.Include(x => x.Relationship).Include(x => x.Case1.CaseNumber).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.From_Case == cases.CaseIdFrom && m.To_Case == cases.CaseIdTo);
                    if (reference != null)
                        {
                            if (cases.Gender == "M")
                            {
                                cases.RelationshipDefinition = await relationshipsdd.Where(r => r.Id == reference.Relationship.Id).Select(r => r.MaleReverseRelationshipDefinition).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                                cases.CaseCrossReferenceId = reference.CaseCrossReferenceId;
                                cases.CaseNumber = reference.Case1.CaseNumber?.Number == null ? null : reference.Case1.CaseNumber.CaseNumberPrefix + "-" + reference.Case1.CaseNumber.Number;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cases.RelationshipDefinition = await relationshipsdd.Where(r => r.Id == reference.Relationship.Id).Select(r => r.FemaleReverseRelationshipDefinition).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                                cases.CaseCrossReferenceId = reference.CaseCrossReferenceId;
                                cases.CaseNumber = reference.Case1.CaseNumber?.Number == null ? null : reference.Case1.CaseNumber.CaseNumberPrefix + "-" + reference.Case1.CaseNumber.Number;
                            }

                        }
            }
```

You might wonder what is **cid**. It's the **CaseID/Case GUID** querystring value. When I'm in **User A**, the cid is the **User A** guid and when I go to **User B** it's the **User B** guid. Simply it's the current Case ID.

***I need to be able to do the following:***

No matter in which User I'm in, I should be able to see the connection to other User(s). If I'm in **User B**, then I should be able to see that I have a connection to **User A** and vice versa.

The image below demonstrates the correct situation as I'm in **PS-100002** and I can see that I have connection to **PS-100000**.
[image: Reference PS-100002]

But if go to **PS-100000**, I still see **PS-100000** as my reference. It needs to be **PS-100002** with the correct **Relationship** (Grand Father).

[image: Reference PS-100000]

Can you please help me to find a proper solution for this matter?

Dedicated room for this topic: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60854/room-for-forrest-and-kevin-maxwell

Comment: Kevin, try defining what PS-XXXX represent or replacing them with easily-recognizable terms. Maybe name them Case <X> if they each represent a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically had to reverse the relationship between members. So I came up with the following solution:

```
var member = await db.Member.Include(x => x.Gender).Include(x => x.Case.CaseNumber)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Relationship.Code == "PA" && x.CaseId == cid && x.Deleted == false);
        var relationshipsdd = db.RelationshipDD;

        var model = new CaseCrossReferenceFromRelationshipViewModel()
        {
            MemberId = member?.MemberId,
            FirstName = member?.FirstName,
            MiddleName = member?.MiddleName,
            LastName = member?.LastName,
            Gender = member?.Gender.Code,
            CaseNumber = member?.Case.CaseNumber?.Number == null
                ? null
                : member.Case.CaseNumber?.CaseNumberPrefix + "-" + member.Case.CaseNumber?.Number,
            CaseId = member?.CaseId,


            ToCases = await db.CaseCrossReference
                .Where(x => (x.From_Case == cid || x.To_Case == cid)
                            && x.Deleted == false)
                .Select(o => new CaseCrossReferenceToRelationshipViewModel()
                {
                    CaseIdFrom = o.From_Case,
                    CaseIdTo = o.To_Case,
                    CaseCrossReferenceId = o.CaseCrossReferenceId,
                    LivingTogether = o.LivingTogether,
                    Gender = o.Relationship.Gender.Code,
                    Split = o.Split,
                    SplitDate = o.SplitDate,
                    SplitReason = o.SplitReason,
                    Type = o.Type.Definition,
                    RelationshipDefinition = o.Relationship.Definition,
                    Relationship = o.Relationship.Id
                }).ToListAsync()
        };


        foreach (var cases in model.ToCases)
        {
            // Check for any reverse relationships/Case Number
            var reference = await db.CaseCrossReference.Include(x => x.Relationship)
                .Include(x => x.Case2.CaseNumber).Include(x => x.Case1.CaseNumber)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.From_Case == cases.CaseIdFrom && m.To_Case == cases.CaseIdTo);

            if (cases.CaseIdFrom == cid)
            {
                member = await db.Member.Include(x => x.Gender)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Relationship.Code == "PA" && x.CaseId == cases.CaseIdTo &&
                                              x.Deleted == false);

                cases.CaseIdFrom = cases.CaseIdTo;
                cases.CaseNumber = reference.Case2.CaseNumber?.Number == null
                    ? null
                    : reference.Case2.CaseNumber.CaseNumberPrefix + "-" + reference.Case2.CaseNumber.Number;
                cases.FirstName = member.FirstName;
                cases.MiddleName = member.MiddleName;
                cases.LastName = member.LastName;

                if (member.Gender.Code == "M")
                {
                    cases.RelationshipDefinition = await relationshipsdd
                        .Where(r => r.Id == reference.Relationship.Id)
                        .Select(r => r.MaleReverseRelationshipDefinition).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    cases.RelationshipDefinition = await relationshipsdd
                        .Where(r => r.Id == reference.Relationship.Id)
                        .Select(r => r.FemaleReverseRelationshipDefinition).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                member = await db.Member.Include(x => x.Gender)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Relationship.Code == "PA" && x.CaseId == cases.CaseIdFrom &&
                                              x.Deleted == false);
                cases.CaseIdTo = cases.CaseIdFrom;
                cases.CaseNumber = reference.Case1.CaseNumber?.Number == null
                    ? null
                    : reference.Case1.CaseNumber.CaseNumberPrefix + "-" + reference.Case1.CaseNumber.Number;
                cases.FirstName = member.FirstName;
                cases.MiddleName = member.MiddleName;
                cases.LastName = member.LastName;
            }
        }


        return View(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't .ToList() the first query.  Once you fetch the results with ToList() you would have to use Lazy Loading to navigate the Navigation Properties.  But if it's in one query, the columns to project the ViewModel type will be fetched in a single SQL Query.

```
ToCases       = await db.CaseCrossReference
                        .Include(x => x.Relationship)
                        .Include(x => x.Type)
                        .Where(x => (x.From_Case == cid || x.To_Case == cid)
                                         && x.Deleted == false)
                        .Select(o => new CaseCrossReferenceToRelationshipViewModel()
                {
                    CaseId = o.From_Case,
                    CaseCrossReferenceId = o.CaseCrossReferenceId,
                    CaseNumber = o.Case2.CaseNumber?.Number == null ? null : o.Case2.CaseNumber.CaseNumberPrefix + "-" + o.Case2.CaseNumber.Number,
                    LivingTogether = o.LivingTogether,
                    Split = o.Split,
                    SplitDate = o.SplitDate,
                    SplitReason = o.SplitReason,
                    Type = o.Type.Definition,
                    RelationshipDefinition = o.Relationship.Definition

                }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. Per your suggestion, I changed my query. The result it's the same but I assume your query would improve the performance, right?

Comment: Yes, performance will be better.  So what is the actual problem?

Comment: Try to create a simplified model and repro, including inserting entity members and expected results.  If you can, post that.